# Rudin functional analysis, Definition 3.26

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, proof-verification, topological-vector-spaces

Straight to the point

> Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on a measure space $Q$,$X$ is a topological vector space on which $X^*$ separates points, and $f$ is a function from $Q$ into $X$ such that the scalar function $\Lambda f$ are integrable with respct to $\mu$, for every $\Lambda \in X^*$; If there exists a vector $y$ such that
>   $$\Lambda y = \int_Q (\Lambda f) d\mu$$
>   for every $\Lambda \in X^*$ we define
>   $$
> \int_Q f d\mu = y
> $$

Now assuming such $y$ exists it is claimed that $y$ is unique due to the separation of $X^*$. Why is that?

Here is my attempt

If $X^*$ separates points then for every $0 \neq y \in X$ there's at least one $X^*$ such that  $\Lambda y \neq 0$. By contradiction if uniqueness wouldn't be true we could get $\Lambda y_1 = \Lambda y_2$ with $y_1 \neq y_2$ but this would imply $\Lambda(y_1 - y_2) = 0$ for every $\Lambda$, but this is false because of the separation property.

Is my proof correct? is basically a straight forward application of the separation property.

Comment: Your proof looks good except that "at least one $X^*$" should be "at least one $\Lambda\in X^*$".

Comment: That's what I meant, thank you very much!